# Add new payment method

Tags: bigcommerce

I would like to implement a new payment gateway via BigCommerce. It would consist in creating a button on Bigcommerce checkout page able to redirect to the payment gateway with payment parameters and subsequently manage the outcome of the transaction. According to BigCommerce live chat this operation is possible, but it's necessary to write in this community for more info (API, etc...). In the specifications we found only these indications https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/store-management/payment-processing . Could you give me some more tips on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

It generally isn't recommended to integrate custom payment gateways, because all existing payment gateways integrated with BigCommerce are integrated through the core application.

If you'd like to use a different gateway, you would need to direct the shopper to your own PCI-Compliant server to process the payment, and then POST the order back to your BigCommerce store through the API.

Answer (score 1):

I'll agree with what Kyle (above) stated, in regards to this not being recommended. Creating new payment integrations are not as straight-forward as other integrations such as shipping or tax for example which use the rest apis in our dev docs. This process is quite rigorous and has many requirements. However, to apply to our partner program and continue the conversation with our team about this type of integration: https://www.bigcommerce.com/partners/become-a-partner/ (technology partner)